# Image File upload with thumbnail preview - like Zurb - not Working?

Tags: jquery, image, wordpress, upload, preview

Here's what I have:

I am trying to implement the ZURB file uploader, however I am having trouble getting the file to upload.  I am wondering if there is something with my upload.php file.  The site runs on wordpress and the form I am working with is part of a user profile creation process.

Here's basically what I want to do:

-Upload image file only as part of a larger form

-The file must go in a custom folder and can be stored there during the profile process (which mat take a few minutes for the user to input all the information).

-Preview the image file as a thumbnail

Here is the JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var thumb = $('img#thumb'); 

new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
    action: $('form#newHotnessForm').attr('action'),
    name: 'userfile',
    onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
        $('div.preview').addClass('loading');
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response) {
        thumb.load(function(){
            $('div.preview').removeClass('loading');
            thumb.unbind();
        });
        thumb.attr('src', response);
    }
});
```

});

Here is the html:

```
<div class="preview">
<img id="thumb" width="50px" height="50px" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/thumbnail.png" />
</div>
<span class="wrap hotness">
<form id="newHotnessForm" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/upload.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>                     
    <input type="file" id="imageUpload" size="20" accept="image/*"/>
    <label>Upload your image</label>
</form>
```

Here is the upload.php file:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES['userfile']["name"]));
if ((($_FILES['userfile']["type"] == "image/gif") 
|| ($_FILES['userfile']["type"] == "image/jpeg") 
|| ($_FILES['userfile']["type"] == "image/jpg") 
|| ($_FILES['userfile']["type"] == "image/png")) 
&& ($_FILES['userfile']["size"] < 20000000) 
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES['userfile']["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES['userfile']["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES['userfile']["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES['userfile']["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES['userfile']["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES['userfile']["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/uploads/" . $_FILES['userfile']["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES['userfile']["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']["tmp_name"], "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/uploads/" . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
  echo "Stored in: " . "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/uploads/" . $_FILES['userfile']["name"];
   }
 }
} else {echo "Invalid file";}
```

I'm wondering if I am missing something here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `name` of the file form element that will be posted to your server. In your case HTML code should be:

```
<input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="userfile" size="20" accept="image/*"/>
```

Comment: Try to replace move_uploaded_file(...) with copy(...)

Comment: tried...still no go.  I really appreciate the assistance here.  I wonder if there is something with wordpress.  I have had some trouble in  the past with some functions not working normally with wordpress.

Comment: Are you sure that you include all necessary JS filew in right place then? Via wp_enqueue_script() function and in right order?

Comment: Before the JS I have the usual:  `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/ajaxupload.js"></script>`     Do I need to use the WP thing?

Comment: It depends of your theme, but in general you should use WP function to load scripts, because this way they will be loaded in right order, one more thing - you need to execute wp_enqueue_script("script_name") BEFORE wp_head();

Comment: OK.  So, I got the script loading using the wp_enqueue_script()...however, still no working file upload.  What about the [ajaxupload.js] file?  Could there be something with that?  Anyone have a nice working version?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the thing to upload files.

Here's how:

1-made the above recommended changes by bodi0 (Thank you!)

2-changed my upload.php file with this:

```
$dirImagePath=dirname(__FILE__);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $dirImagePath.'/uploads/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

What a royal pain this was tying to find the solution to this.